# Getting "SQLServerException: The statement is closed" when calling save(), but save() works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot application and a repository where if I call the save() method the saving works but I still get an com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement is closed. exception. I have never come across this and I honestly have no idea what it could be. Here's the service method which calls the repository:

```
public MatchRequest createNewAndSave(Participant receiverParticipant, Participant senderParticipant) {
    var matchRequest = new MatchRequest();
    matchRequest.setReceiverParticipant(receiverParticipant);
    matchRequest.setSenderParticipant(senderParticipant);
    matchRequest.setMatchRequestStatus(MatchRequestStatus.OPEN);
    return matchRequestRepository.save(matchRequest);
    }
```

The exception occurs in this line `return matchRequestRepository.save(matchRequest)`. The repository is a simple JpaRepository. I don't call `createNewAndSave()` in a loop or something like that. And when I check the data is in the table, so the save itself works. Also, every single other repository and save/delete works flawlessly. It's just this specific one.

Here's the full output (`insert into [someTable] ([someColumns]) values ([someData])` is the desired input statement which does work.) :

```
2023-12-17T17:36:38.624+01:00  INFO 10988 --- [nio-8881-exec-1] jdbc.sqlonly                           : 
insert into [someTable] ([someColumns]) values ([someData]) 

2023-12-17T17:36:38.647+01:00  INFO 10988 --- [nio-8881-exec-1] jdbc.resultsettable                      : 
|---------------|
|generated_keys |
|---------------|
|4              |
|---------------|

2023-12-17T17:36:38.648+01:00 ERROR 10988 --- [nio-8881-exec-1] jdbc.sqlonly                             : 1. PreparedStatement.getMaxRows()

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The statement is closed.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:237) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.checkClosed(SQLServerStatement.java:1103) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getMaxRows(SQLServerStatement.java:1134) ~[mssql-jdbc-11.2.3.jre17.jar:na]
    at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.StatementSpy.getMaxRows(StatementSpy.java:1040) ~[log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1-1.16.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.getMaxRows(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.close(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:193) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.release(ResourceRegistryStandardImpl.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.PreparedStatementDetailsStandard.releaseStatement(PreparedStatementDetailsStandard.java:69) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.mutation.internal.MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.release(MutationExecutorPostInsertSingleTable.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.doStaticInserts(InsertCoordinator.java:188) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.mutation.InsertCoordinator.coordinateInsert(InsertCoordinator.java:112) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2780) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:676) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:291) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:272) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:322) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:180) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.persist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:93) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:77) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:755) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:739) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.13.Final.jar:6.2.13.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy162.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository.support.RepositoryEntityManagerEntityGraphInjector.invoke(RepositoryEntityManagerEntityGraphInjector.java:65) ~[spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy163.persist(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:618) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:288) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:136) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:120) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:516) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:628) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:168) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:143) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:72) ~[spring-data-commons-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository.support.RepositoryMethodInvocation.proceed(RepositoryMethodInvocation.java:23) ~[spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository.support.EntityGraphQueryHintCandidates.doInvoke(EntityGraphQueryHintCandidates.java:96) ~[spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository.support.EntityGraphQueryHintCandidates.invoke(EntityGraphQueryHintCandidates.java:60) ~[spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:164) ~[spring-data-jpa-3.1.5.jar:3.1.5]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at com.cosium.spring.data.jpa.entity.graph.repository.support.DefaultEntityGraphMethods.invoke(DefaultEntityGraphMethods.java:29) ~[spring-data-jpa-entity-graph-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244) ~[spring-aop-6.0.13.jar:6.0.13]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy199.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at some.package.MatchRequestService.createNewAndSave(MatchRequestService.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
```

Comment: Do you also use `JpaRepository` 's `save` function from other services? Do you experience the same error? Or you only experience this error in `MatchRequestRepository`?

Comment: @Wey I use JpaRepository's save function all over the application and it only happens in MatchRequestRepository. That's what's so puzzling to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from the log4j configuration.
In spite of Hibernate operates correctly, log4jdbc attempts to utilize a statement that has already been closed, resulting in an error.
( at net.sf.log4jdbc.sql.jdbcapi.StatementSpy.getMaxRows(StatementSpy.java:1040) ~[log4jdbc-log4j2-jdbc4.1-1.16.jar:na] )

There is no problem, but if it bothers you, there are two possible solutions:

1. Remove the JDBC log configuration in logback-spring.xml (probably don't want to).

2. If the GenerationType in the MatchRequest class is set to GenerationType.IDENTITY, consider using GenerationType.SEQUENCE instead and make use of a SequenceGenerator.

Hope this helps.